# Collect keys from List<HashMap> using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<ExcelData>` called dataBeanList. ExcelData class has variable  `HashMap<String, Integer>` cardNumber.

I want to get all keys from `List<ExcelData>`. I tried below approach but, I obtained `List<List<String>>` values. However I want to get `List<String>` values. Can you help me with that?

```
List<List<String>> collect = dataBeanList
                .stream()
                .map(excelData ->
                        excelData.getCardNumber().keySet()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? can you provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I want to get all keys in a List. Not a List of List

Comment: Use `flatMap(List:stream)` before `collect`. Also, don't you want to use `toSet()` as your final collector?

Comment: @ernest_k could you provide the source code? I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: `dataBeanList.stream().flatMap(excelData -> excelData.getCardNumber().keySet().stream()).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what @ernest_k provided as answer in comment (he also talked about using converting it to a set if the keys are duplicating and you need only distinct ones) :

```
List<String> collect = dataBeanList
                .stream()
                .map(excelData ->
                        excelData.getCardNumber().keySet()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use flatMap whenever you need to create another type of Stream from one Stream.
From documentation -

```
Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing 
each element of his stream with the contents of a mapped stream 
produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element
```

Change your code to -

```
dataBeanList.stream().
                flatMap(excelData -> excelData.getCardNumber().keySet().stream()).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
```